# HTML5 - Three-column layout to magazine/blog-like format?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is my HTML5 layout for a three-column magazine:

```css
article, section, aside, hgroup, nav, header, footer, figure, figcaption { 
  display: block;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  border: none;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 990px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header {
  height: 130px;
}

aside {
  width: 245px;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#rightsidebar {
  width: 245px;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <aside></aside>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="rightsidebar"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

This works for a basic layout but my problem is that i am trying to emulate this design:
http://www.autos.ca/car-test-drives/test-drive-2008-mercedes-benz-c230-4matic/

At the moment my design is basic, but not aesthetically pleasing, and I am trying to improve it so that it's a three-column design with gray header and white background like the example above.

What would I need to add to my CSS stylesheet for this to work?

This is as a template for a Twig-based static site on classic American and Latin American automobiles - the site is not a blog, but an information site.

If anyone can guide me or advise, I'd appreciate it, as this is my first real go at trying to do HTML5 - for years I'd coded HTML in previous HTML4 standards for things.

Comment: Don't use float. Use flex instead.

Comment: Float has no use anymore after flexbox has been given to us by god himself.

Comment: @Phiter it's not good practice to use flex yet, because of the browser support issues. Did you forget that there is a browser from Microsoft?

Comment: @avenas8808 maybe you can point us to a live coding example. It would be easier to see what you are looking for and what we can edit. At the moment you are trying to recreate a two column layout as a three column layout. I would recommend you look into Responsive Web Design as a basic requirement https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Comment: @sanjithedward if nobody use flexbox it'll never be a good practice to use it. It's 2018 already, I think we should stop caring about a browser that almost nobody uses anymore.

Comment: @Phiter I'd go even further and recommend using grid for that layout ;-)

Comment: Grid is cool and fresh but even the most recent browsers don't fully support it yet. (some people disable chrome and firefox auto update... damn those people)